# How to use const in verilog

Tags: constants, verilog, hdl, system-verilog

Instead of using

```
module ... ( .. )  ;

     #15 
endmodule
```

I want use

```
module ... ( ... ) ;
 // GateDelay is a const, like in c language const int GateDelay = 15 ;
 # GateDelay     

endmodule
```

Or same thing

```
module ... ( ... ) ;
 // assume Wordsize is defined at " define Wordsize 15 "
 reg [ Wordsize -1 : 0 ] mem ;

endmodule
```

Can I do that wish in verilog ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You've a few options :

- Macros with `` `define ``s
- `parameter`s
- `localparam`s

Here's a small example with them all.

```
`define CONSTANT_MACRO 1          /* important: no ';' here */
module mymodule
    #( parameter WIDTH = 5 )
    ( 
      input wire [WIDTH-1:0] in_a,
      output wire [WIDTH-1:0] out_a
    );

    localparam CONSTANT_LOCAL = 2;

    assign out_a = in_a + `CONSTANT_MACRO - CONSTANT_LOCAL;

endmodule
```

Comment: SystemVerilog also provides a construct `const` to declare any data type variable value as a constant.

Answer (score 6):

For the cases you listed, I would recommend parameters.

Like the C compiler directive, `define is global for the compilation. If your code is ever going to be used with code you don't control you will need to be careful here.

Parameters are always local to the module scope so identically named parameters in different design elements will not conflict with each other. They also have the advantage that they can be overridden on a per-instance basis.

```
module #(parameter DATA_WIDTH = 1) busSlave(
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] bus_data,
  input                  bus_wr,
  ...
);

endmodule


module top;

  //DATA_WIDTH is 32 in this instance
  busSlave #(.DATA_WIDTH(32)) slave32(
    .bus_data(data_0),
    .bus_wr(wr_0),
    ...
    );

  //DATA_WIDTH is 64 in this instance
  busSlave #(.DATA_WIDTH(64)) slave64(
    .bus_data(data_1),
    .bus_wr(wr_1),
    ...
    );


endmodule
```